# Convert eloquent object to array collection

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

This is my select statement:

```
$users = User::where("username", "LIKE", "%" . $query . "%")
    ->select("username")
    ->get();
```

This currently outputs as:

```
[{"username":"Test"}]
```

I need it to output in one of the following formats:

```
{ 'data': ['result1', 'result2', ... ] }

OR

['result1', 'result2', ...]
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 4):

```
$users = User::where("username", "LIKE", "%" . $query . "%")->select("username")->get()->toArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

Spoke too soon:

```
$users = User::where("username", "LIKE", "%" . $query . "%")
    ->lists("username");

return Response::json(array("data" => $users));
```

Comment: and `User::where("username", "LIKE", "%" . $query . "%")->lists("username")->toArray();` doesn't work ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use plain PHP. 
Just reverse-json the object.

In your case, you can do $users=@json_decode(json_encode($users), true);

Or you can add a static method to your parent or current controller like this

```
public static function objectToArray(&$object)
{
    return @json_decode(json_encode($object), true);
}
```